# How to match large dataframe and rbind in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working on following dataframe.

File1:

```
UniqueId     Match_ID               Parameters     Value
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Age            28
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Sex            Male
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Height         5.7
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Balance        200
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Balance        303
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Weight         89
```

File2:

```
UniqueId     Match_ID               Parameters     Value
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Age            29
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Sex            Female
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Height         5.7
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Balance        200
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Balance        300
```

I need to compare both the datafrme and required the following output on distinct `UniqueId` basis.

Where, We need to compare `File1` Parameters Value with `File2` to check if both are exact match or not. Also, We need to create a comma separated string of Mismatched Parameters in output dataframe as `Variable_Mismatched`.

```
UniqueID   Count_File1  Count_File2 Matched_Parameters   Mismatched_Parameters   Variable_Mismatched
UID-245     4            4            2                   2                      Age,Sex
UID-246     2            1            0                   1                      Balance
```

Comment: You are disregarding the `weight`-parameter in File1, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach. explanation is in the code's comments

Make sure your `File1` and `File2` are in `data.table`-format. This can be done by reading the fils in using `data.table::fread()`, or by using `data.table::setDT()` on existing `data.frames`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble) #for lst-function
# Sample data -----
File1 <- fread("UniqueId     Match_ID               Parameters     Value
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Age            28
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Sex            Male
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Height         5.7
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Balance        200
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Balance        303
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Weight         89")
File2 <- fread("UniqueId     Match_ID               Parameters     Value
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Age            29
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Sex            Female
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Height         5.7
UID-245       xty-tt09-23-ert        Balance        200
UID-246       xty-tt09-03-ert        Balance        300")

# Part 1: get counts per file & UniqueId -----
L <- tibble::lst(File1, File2)
DT <- rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "File")
# Summarise by UniqueId to get file-count, the first part of the answer
ans1 <- dcast(DT[, .N, by = .(File, UniqueId)], 
             UniqueId ~ paste0("Count_", File),
             value.var = "N")
# Part 2: Find matches and mismatches -----
ans2 <- copy(File1)[ File2, Value2 := i.Value, on = .(UniqueId, Parameters)]
# Only keep complete cases
ans2 <- ans2[!is.na(Value) & !is.na(Value2), ]
ans2 <- ans2[, .(Matched_Parameters    = sum(Value == Value2),
                 Mismatched_Parameters = sum(!Value == Value2),
                 Variable_Mismatched   = paste0(Parameters[!Value == Value2], 
                                                collapse = ","),
                 Variable_Matched      = paste0(Parameters[Value == Value2], 
                                                collapse = ",")), 
             by = .(UniqueId)]
# Part 3: Join together -----
ans1[ans2, on = .(UniqueId)]
#    UniqueId Count_File1 Count_File2 Matched_Parameters Mismatched_Parameters Variable_Mismatched Variable_Matched
# 1:  UID-245           4           4                  2                     2             Age,Sex   Height,Balance
# 2:  UID-246           2           1                  0                     1             Balance
```

Comment: How can I add one more column which shows those variables in comma separated which matched in both the files.